# Relocate Linux System Copying Linux Partitions Only

Tags: partition, cloning

I have the next HDD **MSDOS** configuration in sda:

```
jeanfar@jeanfar-pc:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: ST250LM004 HN-M2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00066607

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   1026047   1024000  500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *      1026048 210741247 209715200  100G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       210741248 211781631   1040384  508M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       211783678 480217087 268433410  128G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       211783680 278893054  67109375   32G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       278894592 446666751 167772160   80G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

sda4 is an extended partition, which contains sda5 (/) and sda6 (/home) partitions.

If I want to copy just sda5 and sda6 ("extracting out these") to a clean **GPT** sbd disk, and set boot parameter to sdb5 (/), could I boot?

Which is the best way to transfer just my linux system to other disk with other partitioning configuration?

Comment: Linux is quite the flexible OS, thus you can move it around and as long as your bootloader knows where it is, it will boot. But first, are you certain the computer can boot from a GPT-partitioned disk? Usually that functionality is reserved for UEFI systems. Which distro are you using?

Comment: Yes. I'm totally sure. Debian 10.1.